# Truth is singular. Its "versions" are mistruths

Tags: logic, ethics, epistemology, truth

In the beginning of the legendary movie called Cloud Atlas... Somni 541 is sitting in a room, and an "Archivist" comes in. The conversation starts...

Archivist:

> On behalf of my Ministry and the future of Unanimity, I want to thank you for the final interview. Remember, this isn't an interrogation or trial. Your version of the truth is all that matters.

Sonmi 541:

> Truth is singular. Its "versions" are mistruths.

I am stuck on her statement of what she actually means... is it that each version of the truth is actually the truth, is hers the truth? Or is someone elses the truth?

A few friends and I have tried to analyze what she is meaning, but we are clueless.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not appear to really be sufficiently focused to be a philosophy question. This sounds like a movie interpretation question.

Comment: @virmaior We usually encourage people to disclose the practical worry that prompts a philosophical question. In this case it's a movie which prompts an old standing philosophical question, which seems perfectly on-topic.

Comment: I haven't read the book or seen the film - which is why this is a comment rather than an answer; Somnis answer has the tone of a ritualised reply, which might be expected when confronted with authority in the context of a totalitarian state. The archivist, is allowing her the rare freedom of expressing her views, her truth, which in fact might be the actual truth, but which cannot in normal circumstances be allowed to disturb the 'unanimity' of thought. By affirming that truth is singular,

Comment: she is affirming that the State is Truth itself, and any other truths are 'mistruths'. I'd align this with Orwells 1984, which it appears to share similar political concerns.

Comment: Sorry guys, the question is based around the concept of truth, which Sonmi does provide the actual truth throughout the whole story and movie. Worth watching also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of analyzing it. Consider the predicate 'Thinks(α, φ)', which is true just in case agent α thinks that φ is true. Let A be the Archivist, and A Sonmi 541. Let's begin by looking at what A says:

> Ω = { φ : Thinks(S, φ) }.

Ω stands for the set of "things that matter", which according to A is the set of all those propositions φ (about events and so on) that S thinks to be true. We can assume that there is another set Σ s.t.:

> Σ = { φ : True(φ) }.

This is the set of those propositions φ that are *actually* true. Depending on which set-theoretic relations hold between Ω and Σ (e.g. Ω ⊂ Σ, Ω ∩ Σ = ∅, etc.), Sonmi's version of the truth may or may not coincide with the actual truth. Now let's look at the things S says:

> (1) Truth is singular.
>
> (2) 'Versions' of the truth are mistruths.

I take it that (1) means that:

> (1) ∀φ, α, β( [φ ∈ Ω<sub>α</sub> ≡ φ ∈ Ω<sub>β</sub>] → Ω<sub>α</sub> = Ω<sub>β</sub>).

This says that given any two agents α and β, if a proposition φ is among the truths recognized by α (Ω<sub>α</sub>) if and only if φ is among the truths recognized by β (Ω<sub>β</sub>), then the truths recognized by α are β are the same. So for any two different 'versions' of the truth, there must be a φ that belongs to one but not to the other. If one of these guys is right, then both are and their Ωs coincide with Σ (the set of all truths).

From that reasoning, (2) doesn't follow; what follows is this:

> (*) ∀α, β ( ¬[Ω<sub>α</sub> = Ω<sub>β</sub>]  → ∃φ[φ ∈ Ω<sub>α</sub> ∧ ¬(φ ∈ Ω<sub>β</sub>)] ).

Which says that if two agents have different 'versions' of the truth, then there is some proposition that one thinks to be true while the other thinks to be false. But (2) says that in that case both Ωs are 'mistruth's, i.e., neither Ω<sub>α</sub> nor Ω<sub>β</sub> is a subset of Σ:

> (2) ∀α, β ( ¬[Ω<sub>α</sub> = Ω<sub>β</sub>]  → ¬[Ω<sub>α</sub> ⊂ Σ ∨ Ω<sub>β</sub> ⊂ Σ] ).

This, of course, doesn't follow from previous reasoning, because it's possible that one of the Ωs coincides with Σ. All we can conclude is that *at most* one can, because of the disagreement, because of the fact that they are genuinely different 'versions' of what happened.

As I said, 'versions' in that context seems to me to contain assumptions that we might want to reject, so that, for example, we'll be able to say that two 'versions' of what happened yesterday may both be true.